# Different code behavior in multiple files compared to collocated into single file

Tags: c++

Code that I place in a single file behaves differently when separated into multiple files. I have a `static` field in a class (a `std::vector`) that I am modifying during global object instantiation which I analyze in `main`.

I suspect this is due to how objects are created in different scopes, but I thought this scenario would result in sharing the same object.

**How can I separate this code and get the same result I see when the code is collocated?**

**UPDATE** If I declare the static object in main.cpp the code works. Is this the only way? That feels messy, it's not where I want to declare it.

Here is the code.

utils.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Collector
{
public:
  static std::vector<int> Ints;
};


class Aggregator
{
public:
  Aggregator(int i);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "utils.h"

// as noted in my updated question, if I declare Ints here, it works
// std::vector<int> Collector::Ints;
// but I want the freedom to declare this in any source

Aggregator inst(1);

int main()
{
  std::cout << "size: " << Collector::Ints.size();

  std::cin.get();

  return 1;
}
```

utils.cpp

```
#include "utils.h"

std::vector<int> Collector::Ints;

Aggregator::Aggregator(int i)
{
  Collector::Ints.push_back(i);
}
```

The output is `size: 0`

And all the same code in one file would look like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Collector
{
public:
  static std::vector<int> Ints;
};


class Aggregator
{
public:
  Aggregator(int i);
};

#include "utils.h"

std::vector<int> Collector::Ints;

Aggregator::Aggregator(int i)
{
  Collector::Ints.push_back(i);
}

Aggregator inst(1);

int main()
{
  std::cout << "size: " << Collector::Ints.size();

  std::cin.get();

  return 1;
}
```

And this outputs `size: 1`, as I desire.

Comment: Move `Aggregator inst(1);` inside main()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid this is to use a static function with a static variable in it.
So for example:

```
class Collector
{
public:
  static std::vector<int> & GetInts(){ static std::vector<int> Ints; return Ints; }
};
```

This way you are guaranteed the static variable is initialized when you use it regardless of which cpp file you're using it in.

I should stress though that this is not a great idea as you'll have issues with threading. Is there a good reason to make this static?

Comment: This solution will work just fine, thank you. I'm still curious _why_ my original code doesn't work. I'll investigate that more on my own time. But for now, your suggestion is great. Let me point out that I typically stay away from statics, and definitely don't like the model I'm using them for in this scenario; it's a hack. But I'm just building some play-code and wanted a quick and dirty way to have some reflective type metadata about my code and am using this Aggregator to essentially tag specific areas of interest.